# Array Function required in replace foreach

Tags: php, foreach

I want to get validation message by using any `php` function not by foreach. 
Here is my demo code

```
Array
(
    [SeriesConcateCharacter] => Array
        (
            [0] => Please enter only spaecial characters.
        )

    [NumberPaddingCharacter] => Array
        (
            [0] => You cannot enter more than 1 character.
        )

)
```

I want direct

> [0] => Please enter only spaecial characters. and
>   [0] => You cannot enter more than 1 character.

by using php function. So please suggest me appropriate solution.

Comment: Why don't you wan foreach?

Comment: You can't, because that means you have two entries both with a key of `0`... array keys must be unique

Comment: Beacuse by using 2 forloop form this array..so i direct msg want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [*Mark*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324584/mark-baker) mentioned , You **cannot** have same indices for an array.. Use an `array_walk()` to get the output as shown.

```
$new_arr = array();
array_walk($arr,function ($v,$k) use (&$new_arr) { $new_arr[]=$v[0];} );
print_r($new_arr);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Please enter only spaecial characters.
    [1] => You cannot enter more than 1 character.
)
```

[<kbd>Working Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/138169)

Comment: You want to print them or you want them in a string ?

Comment: it will dispaly in one row ,pls use next line

Comment: Use `<br>` in the place of `\n`

Answer (score 0):

I think this  will help you...........

```
 //declare your array
    $array=array('SeriesConcateCharacter'=>array('Please enter only spaecial characters.'),
                'NumberPaddingCharacter'=>array('You cannot enter more than 1 character.'));

    //this function will remove all your unwanted keys
    $array1=array_values($array);
    foreach($array1 as $val){
        echo "<pre>"; print_r($val);
        //Array
        //(
        //    [0] => Please enter only spaecial characters.
        //)

        //Array
        //(
        //    [0] => You cannot enter more than 1 character.
        //)


    }
```